# How can I link my local node js code and azure web?

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code

I made my node js basic template and want to host as azure.

I followed instruction below
https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs

[image]

by clicking browse website. I think it redirect to azure web. 
but I made local node js and want to link it to azure web. 
how can I link it? instruction dosen't mention it any.

Comment: You need to Deploy to web app and open the web app from the portal

Comment: Sorry for not understanding what you said. According to official documents, webapps can be created and published. The `Browse Website` that you want to click should only jump to the published website after successful deployment.

Comment: Generally speaking, the nodejs webapp program will not be released until there is no problem running locally. If debugging is needed, it is generally debugged locally. The command to start the webapp project locally is generally `npm run dev`.